# Website becomes unusable while downloading file served by PHP script

Tags: php, iis

I'm running IIS 8.0 and have a script that serves various downloads when someone clicks on a download link. However I'm running into an issue where as long as a user is downloading something the website is completely unresponsive until that download completes. Below is the code for the download script. This script is being opened in a new window.

```
$extension = fileexten($filename);
if(($filename!= false)&&($fakename!=false&& @fopen($filename,'r')==true)){
  $mime = contenttype($extension);
  set_time_limit(0);
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Expires: 0'); 
  header("Content-Type:".$mime);
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Cache-Control: private', false);        
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fakename.'.'.$extension);
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
  }
  flush();
  readfile($filename);
}
else{
  $error = "<h3>We could not find this file</h3>";} // If the filename or fake filename could not be retrieved. 
}
```

Comment: How big is the file? Are you reading the file into memory everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the session before outputting the file.

```
session_write_close();
readfile($filename);
```

The session can only be opened by one PHP process at a time, and any other requests that issue a `session_start()` command will block while waiting for access to the session data file.