# File download blocks everything

Tags: php, download

I am downloading a file with the following code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);


readfile($download_url);             
exit;
```

where `$download_url` is the file path. File is downloading perfect but I can't download next file on same page while first is downloading or even navigate to other pages until download complete or canceled.

Comment: So what do want to achieve? Also I assume the page is loading as long as the download is in progress, the browser/client should still be responsive and not appear "frozen".

Comment: No the page isn't loading while downloading. but when i want to download the 2nd file it starts processing. as i described i cant navigate to other pages or download another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065439/website-becomes-unusable-while-downloading-file-served-by-php-script). I had to close the session before outputting the file.

```
session_write_close();
readfile($download_url);
```

The session can only be opened by one PHP process at a time, and any other requests that issue a session_start() command will block while waiting for access to the session data file.

Answer (score -1):

I tried under Wamp and that had some problems.

After a lot of searchs, I ended up with this working code

```
$file = 'test.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it isn't working for me . I tried using same headers but the filename and size are different variables. still no luck.

Comment: maybe it's the browser , can you try in private navigation ?

Comment: private navigation ?

Comment: it is same there too.

Comment: what about `file_put_contents("test.jpg", fopen("http://someurl/test.jpg", 'r'));` ?

Comment: it keeps processing . My file is big like min 400MB so i think it will keep processing until it downloads.

Comment: That's normal you have to wait until the download is done

Comment: is there any way that after downloading first file i can do other functionalities like navigation,downloading another file etc.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152096/discussion-between-soltani-neji-and-nomi).